# Getting Error code: -2146368511 [0x80110401] on executing Sample VSS Hardware provider setup

Tags: c++, windows, com, com+, volume-shadow-service

Both the solutions mentioned in "[VSS Hardware provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384896/vss-hardware-provider)" are not helpful.

I executed following instructions to install VssSampleProvider Setup (refered from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VSS-Sample-Provider-3096be2a/sourcecode?fileId=58709&pathId=1834493409).

(1) Install the virtual storage driver as follows:

```
a.  Navigate to the Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86 directory in the Windows SDK. This directory contains virtualstoragevss.sys and vstorcontrol.exe.
```

(2) Install the VSS sample provider as follows:

```
a.  Copy the following files from the Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86 directory into the VssSampleProvider directory in the downloaded sample.

    -   VssSampleProvider.dll
    -   VstorInterface.dll
    -   install-sampleprovider.cmd
    -   uninstall-sampleprovider.cmd
    -   register_app.vbs
b.  In the VssSampleProvider directory, type "install-sampleprovider.cmd" at the command prompt.
```

I am getting following error after executing "install-sampleprovider.cmd" from command prompt:

ERROR:

```
- Error code: -2146368511 [0x80110401]
- Exit code: 113
- Description:
- Source:
- Help file:
- Help context: 0
- COM+ Errors detected: (2)
   * (COM+ ERROR 0) on C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\VssSampleProvider.dll
       ErrorCode: -2146368486 [0x8011041A]
       MajorRef: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\VssSampleProvider.dll
       MinorRef: <invalid>
   * (COM+ ERROR 1) on SampleProvider
       ErrorCode: -2146368486 [0x8011041A]
       MajorRef: {423BBC78-9B20-4BBE-A967-B63EC43BC7F3}
       MinorRef: <invalid>
```

**Command prompt console logs:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>install-sampleprovider.cmd

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>rem Remove existing installation

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>call "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\\uninstall-sampleprovider.cmd"

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>net stop vds
The Virtual Disk service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.


C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>net stop vss
The Volume Shadow Copy service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.


C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>net stop swprv
The Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.


C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>reg.exe delete HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\VssSampleProvider /f
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>cscript "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\\register_app.vbs" -unregister "VssSampleProvider"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

REGISTER_APP.VBS version 1.6 for Windows Server 2008
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2002-2003. All rights reserved.

Unregistering the existing application...
- Create the catalog object
- Get the Applications collection
- Populate...
- Search for VssSampleProvider application...
- Application VssSampleProvider removed!
- Saving changes...
Done.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>regsvr32 /s /u "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\\VssSampleProvider.dll"

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>echo.


C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>goto :EOF

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>rem Register VSS hardware provider

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>cscript "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\register_app.vbs" -register "VssSampleProvider" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\VssSampleProvider.dll" "VSS HW Sample Provider"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


REGISTER_APP.VBS version 1.6 for Windows Server 2008
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2002-2003. All rights reserved.

Unregistering the existing application...
- Create the catalog object
- Get the Applications collection
- Populate...
- Search for VssSampleProvider application...
- Saving changes...
Done.
Creating a new COM+ application:
- Creating the catalog object
- Get the Applications collection
- Populate...
- Add new application object
- Set app name = VssSampleProvider
- Set app description = VSS HW Sample Provider
- Set app access check = true
- Set encrypted COM communication = true
- Set secure references = true
- Set impersonation = false
- Save changes...
- Create Windows service running as Local System
- Add the DLL component

ERROR:
- Error code: -2146368511 [0x80110401]
- Exit code: 113
- Description:
- Source:
- Help file:
- Help context: 0
- COM+ Errors detected: (2)
   * (COM+ ERROR 0) on C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\VssSampleProvider.dll
       ErrorCode: -2146368486 [0x8011041A]
       MajorRef: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\VssSampleProvider.dll
       MinorRef: <invalid>
   * (COM+ ERROR 1) on SampleProvider
       ErrorCode: -2146368486 [0x8011041A]
       MajorRef: {423BBC78-9B20-4BBE-A967-B63EC43BC7F3}
       MinorRef: <invalid>

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>set EVENT_LOG=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\VssSampleProvider

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>reg.exe add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\VssSampleProvider /f
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>reg.exe add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\VssSampleProvider /f /v CustomSource /t REG_DWORD /d 1
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>reg.exe add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\VssSampleProvider /f /v EventMessageFile /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++\VssSampleProvider.dll"
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>reg.exe add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\VssSampleProvider /f /v TypesSupported /t REG_DWORD /d 7
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>echo.


C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Volume Shadow Copy Service hardware provider sample\C++>goto :EOF
```

Comment: Probably the wrong place to ask this question because it doesn't look like you got past configuration and into code. You might want to try Superuser, but having a chat with Microsoft is probably a better option. Otherwise you could be idling here for a long time before someone else who's had this problem wanders by and replies.

Comment: Hi Ankur, I know its been a long time, but I'm facing the exact same issue. Where you able to find out the solution for it? what causes the error? I'm stuck as I don't have any clue on this. Please help. Thanks.